# Best practices for setting autolayout width and height constraints for a collection view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I'm designing the UI of an ios 8 app being built in swift. I have intermediate knowledge of autolayout and constraints. Here's my situation: I have a custom collection view controller and collection view cell. I want to use the "equal widths" and "equal heights" constraints within interface builder to set the width and height of a cell relative to a multiplier of the parent view-- as opposed to using intrinsic height/width properties such as 320 x 94.

Here's what  I tried

1. using intrinsic width and height for size classes within IB. (This doesn't work)
2. Control-Dragging from a UICollectionViewCell to the CollectionView (didn't work seeing as "equal heights " and "equal widths" are not even constraint options)

Should I just settle for the intrinsic height and width and assume that CollectionViewFlowLayout will take care of me or is there  a way to do this programatically?

Thanks.
Alex

Comment: Nobody seams to know the answer to this. It's very annoying to make collection views and you can't watch the preview of what you are editing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` methods to tune your cell size

for example if you want 3 cells across the view width

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    let width = CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.bounds)
    let hcount = 3
    let gapcount = CGFloat(hcount) + 1
    //this should be a class var/constant which you can feed into the minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex delegate
    let gap = 10 
    let kwidth = width - gap
    let keywidth = kwidth/CGFloat(hcount)

    return CGSize(width:keywidth,height:50)
}
```

You can tune the distance between the cells with

`func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat`

and the edge insets with

`func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets`

Answer (score 0):

Layout and size of cells is done by the *collectionViewLayout* property of *collectionView*. Using a *collectionViewLayout* of class UICollectionViewFlowLayout, you can set fixed size using item size property:

```
(collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout)?.itemSize = 100 //set fixed size here
```

or set variable size using delegate method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // determine variable size here using indexPath value
}
```